# Simple GLSL render chain doesn't draw reliably

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a simple compositing system which is supposed to render different textures and a background texture into an FBO. It also renders some primitives.
Here's an example:

[image: Sample rendering]

I'm rendering using a simple GLSL shader for the texture and another one for the primitive. Also, I'm waiting for each shader to finish using `glFinish` after each `glDrawArrays` call.
So basically:

- tex shader (background tex)
- tex shader (tex 1)
- primitive shader
- tex shader (tex 2)
- tex shader (tex 3)

When I only do this once, it works. But if I do another render pass directly after the first one finished, some textures just aren't rendered.
The primitive however is always rendered.
This doesn't happen always, but the more textures I draw, the more often this occurs.

Thus, I'm assuming that this is a timing problem.
I tried to troubleshoot for the last two days and I just can't find the reason for this.

I'm 100% sure that the textures are always valid (I downloaded them using `glGetTexImage` to verify).

Here are my texture shaders.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 150

uniform mat4 mvp;
in vec2 inPosition;
in vec2 inTexCoord;

out vec2 texCoordV;

void main(void)
{
    texCoordV = inTexCoord;
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(inPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 150

uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec2 texCoordV;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(void)
{
    fragColor = texture(tex, texCoordV);
}
```

And here's my invocation:

```
NSRect drawDestRect = NSMakeRect(xPos, yPos, str.texSize.width, str.texSize.height);
NLA_VertexRect rect = NLA_VertexRectFromNSRect(drawDestRect);
int texID = 0;
NLA_VertexRect texCoords = NLA_VertexRectFromNSRect(NSMakeRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
NLA_VertexRectFlipY(&texCoords);

[self.texApplyShader.arguments[@"inTexCoord"] setValue:&texCoords forNumberOfVertices:4];
[self.texApplyShader.arguments[@"inPosition"] setValue:&rect forNumberOfVertices:4];
[self.texApplyShader.arguments[@"tex"] setValue:&texID forNumberOfVertices:1];
GetError();

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, str.texName);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
glFinish();
```

The `setValue:forNumberOfCoordinates:` function is an object-based wrapper around OpenGL's parameter application functions. It basically does this:

```
glBindVertexArray(_vertexArrayObject);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferObject);      
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bytesForGLType * numVertices, value, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)self.boundLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)self.boundLocation, numVectorElementsForType, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

Here are two screenshots of what it should look like (taken after first render pass) and what it actually looks like (taken after second render pass):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nmquelzo83ekf6/GLRendering_issues_correct.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7aztfba5mbeq5sj/GLRendering_issues_wrong.png?dl=0

(in this example, the background texture is just black)

The primitive shader is as simple as it gets:
Vertex:

```
#version 150

uniform mat4 mvp;
uniform vec4 inColor;

in vec2 inPosition;
out vec4 colorV;

void main (void)
{
    colorV = inColor;
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(inPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 150

in vec4 colorV;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(void)
{
    fragColor = colorV;
}
```

Comment: While I dont see any problems. Why do you need `mvp` transformation during the texture composting? you can simply skip it and give the coordinates in the projection space.

Comment: Can you give us a executable code. So, we can reproduce the error and try it?

Comment: Can you give us one or two screenshot that shows two different textures are not shown with each other?

What I want to know is are the two different textures shown in different positions in the window or they are in the same positions?

Comment: I would be happy to prepare a test project (with some effort) but only if you are on Mac. Are you?

Comment: No. Unfortunately I don't have. But I think the opengl code is easily portable. So, if I just copy your code buffer creation and drawing in my code, everything should work fine.

Comment: Could you contribute with the primitive shaders as well as the rendering call for them?

Comment: Would also be suitable to see some screenshots.

Comment: I just tried to isolate the problem but only using the texture shaders alone repeatedly doesn't seem to cause this issue. I might add that I'm using shared contexts only if it matters. Will add more code to the question

Comment: @mmostajab , SporreKing : Thanks for your help guys! I found the issue myself (see answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue... I didn't realize that the FBO is drawn to the screen already after the first render pass. This happens on a different thread and wasn't locked properly.

Apparently the context was switched while the compositing took place which explains why it caused different issues randomly depending on when the second thread switched the context.